# Enable auto shrink by default in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

Is there any possibility to enable auto shrink by default for `UILabel`s and `UIButton`s?

Basically, I would need for them to be run this code:

```
self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
```

even if they are initialized from `.xib` files or from code, and without the need to replace with a custom `MyLabel`.

Comment: That would probably be a bad idea. You don't want to modify system created labels or labels created by third party frameworks, just you own. So the custom subclass is the way to go...

Comment: Well, I think that the way it is now is wrong. I have localization for my app in ~30 languages, and the easiest way to ensure the text doesn't get truncated in a couple of views from the hundreds and a couple of languages from those is by enabling auto shrink for all of them.

Comment: Well then check out method swizzling (and swizzle `UILabel` designated initializer). But I still think this a bad idea...

Comment: Ok, I understand that's a bad idea, I'll consider another solution. But, for the sake of the question, leaving aside best practices, your swizzle answer is perfectly correct. Could you please post a small example or a reference __along__ with the recommendation to avoid using it in real life apps as answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although **I strongly advise against it** (as mentioned in [the question comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392424/enable-auto-shrink-by-default-in-objective-c/33392903#comment54576553_33392424)), here is a way to achieve this using `method swizzling` and a `category`:

**UILabel+SwizzledInitializer.h**:

```
//
//  UILabel+SwizzledInitializer.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (SwizzledInitializer)

@end
```

**UILabel+SwizzledInitializer.m**:

```
//
//  UILabel+SwizzledInitializer.m
//

#import "UILabel+SwizzledInitializer.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UILabel (SwizzledInitializer)

+ (void)load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(initWithFrame:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(initWithFrame_swizzledForAutoShrink:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame_swizzledForAutoShrink:(CGRect)frame;
{
    self = [self initWithFrame_swizzledForAutoShrink:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        self.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Nice, I knew about swizzling but forgot it, though I didn't know how to implement it. Might come in handy in other situations too.

Comment: Here is my reference : http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ (You can read the whole site when you get the time, it's nothing but good stuff)

Comment: Doesn't `[UILabel appearance].adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; [UILabel appearance].minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;` work too?

Comment: In general, only methods or properties tagged with the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` macro work with the appearance proxy. However, sometimes untagged properties work too, so you should just try it.